# Python: Sorting and printing lists within lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

Given a list:

`lists = [[5, 8, 2, "Banana"][3, 6, 9, "Apple"][7, 9, 1, "Cherry"]]`

1) How do I print the list sorted alphabetically AND with the 2nd number in the list only?

Desired output:

`[6, "Apple"][8, "Banana"][9, "Cherry"]`

2) Print the sorted list by the 3rd number highest to lowest

Desired output:

`[3, 6, 9, "Apple"] [5, 8, 2, "Banana"][7, 9, 1, "Cherry"]`

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. All who ask questions here must demonstrate some research effort and/or attempts to solve the problem themselves. Afterwards, we will be more than happy to help with any specific issues you are having.

Comment: Fix your lists! `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you just want code it sounds like

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(map(itemgetter(1,-1),lists),key=itemgetter(-1))
```

heres some code that should do what you want ... a teacher may want an explanation however... just fair warning

Answer (score 0):

here it is: there should be comma for every sublist

```
 l = [[5, 8, 2, "Banana"],[3, 6, 9, "Apple"],[7, 9, 1, "Cherry"]]   
[ x[1::2]for x in sorted(l,key=lambda x : x[2]) ]
```

output:

```
[[9, 'Cherry'], [8, 'Banana'], [6, 'Apple']]
```

then sorted using `key=reverse`

like this one:

```
sorted([ x[1::2] for x in sorted(l,key=lambda x : x[2]) ],key=lambda x:x[-1])
```

output:

```
[[6, 'Apple'], [8, 'Banana'], [9, 'Cherry']]
```

Comment: @jaron yep teacher will need explanation

Comment: Also, this is wrong, check the first post ;)

Comment: my bad sorry let me correct it , ahh dident seen it

Comment: @plg thans to notifying me, i printed the wrong index,now check

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> sorted([[i[1], i[-1]] for i in lists], key=lambda x:x[1])
[[6, 'Apple'], [8, 'Banana'], [9, 'Cherry']]
```